# Isolate a variable in this financial formula

Tags: polynomials, finance

I'm trying to build a programming function that returns the value of CET so I need to isolate it.

How can I isolate CET so I get something that can I linearly solve using a programming language? Something like CET = ...

This is the formula:
$$\sum_{j=1}^n \frac{FC_j}{(1+CET)^{\frac{(d_j-d_0)}{365}}} - FC_0 = 0.$$

Answer (score 1):

There is no general formula for $CET$.  This is a generalized polynomial equation, with the term $\frac{1}{1+CET}$ raised to potentially non-integer powers, none of which powers have any obvious relation to the others.  The only thing I can think of is to use a good solver in your programming language (which is...?) along with a good estimate of $CET$.